# Linq find method

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm currently developing an asp.net mvc application using linq and razor as view engine.

I have 2 doubts using the find method in linq, taking as example this database model:

[image]

If I use the find method to find a product:

```
Product MyProduct = model.products.Find(id);
```

The request to the database it's like an `IEnumerable` where you select all and do the select method in local memory or you only recieve 1 record from the database?

Also do you recieve all the data related to that product like order details?, for example if I do this:

```
var OrderDetails = MyProduct.OrderDetails.Where(x=>x.unitprice>10);
```

The select method it's in local memory (because you already have the related data there) or you make another request to the database?

Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at eager vs lazy loading using the Entity Framework. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx

Comment: Have you seen my answer?

Answer (score 3):

> The request to the database it's like an IEnumerable where you select all and do the select method in local memory or you only recieve 1 record from the database?

You receive only one record. Here you are using `Find` method on your `DbSet<Product>` so Entity Framework will first look if your context already load the related entity. If the entity is loaded then it returns that. If not then it generate a SQL Query to load the product that has its primary key equals to the `id` you pass to the `Find` method. Finally either on local or from the server, the instruction `model.products.Find(id)` will never load all products but the only one you need by specifing its primary key.

> Also do you recieve all the data related to that product like order details?

If you enabled **lazy loading** then you will automatically load all order details related to your product.

If you don't enable **lazy loading** then you will need to use **eager loading** or **explicit loading** for the related order details of your product.

To **eager load** your order details you must use `Include` extension method like below:

```
Product MyProduct = model.products.Include("OrderDetails").Find(id);
```

To **explictly load** your order details you must use `Load` on your collection property like below:

```
Product MyProduct = model.products.Find(id);
model.Entry(MyProduct).Collection(p => p.OrderDetails).Load();
```

> The select method it's in local memory (because you already have the
>   related data there) or you make another request to the database?

```
var OrderDetails = MyProduct.OrderDetails.Where(x=>x.unitprice>10);
```

If you're using **eager loading** or **lazy loading** then the above instruction will filter in memory.

With **explicit loading**, you can filter from your database and load only the related order details you want by doing this:

```
Product MyProduct = model.products.Find(id);
model.Entry(MyProduct)
     .Collection(p => p.OrderDetails)
     .Query()
     .Where(x=>x.unitprice>10)
     .Load();
```

With the instructions above the `OrderDetails` navigational property of your product will only contain the order details you want to load from your database.